# Uninstalling homebrew completely

Tags: macos, homebrew

I uninstalled Homebrew but got this response:

The following possible Homebrew files were not deleted:
`/opt/homebrew/etc/ /opt/homebrew/share/ /opt/homebrew/var/`
You may wish to remove them yourself.

I want to know if these directories can be left alone and if not, how can I remove them?
I don't know how to manage Terminal so I don't want to mess anything on my computer up.

I tried deleting them with rm -rf but got this response:

`rm -rf/opt/homebrew/share/ rm: illegal option -- / usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dIPRrvWx] file ... unlink [--] file`

Answer (score 0):

There's an [uninstall script](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#how-do-i-uninstall-homebrew) in Homebrew's [homebrew/install](https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew) repository.

Comment: I know, and i used it but i got the response i put on the initial post. Can those files be left alone or is it best to delete them?

Comment: You're fine to delete those files. It looks like you're missing a space between `rm -rf` and the path `/opt/homebrew/share/`, which is probably why your command failed.

Comment: I did that and terminal didn't give any type of response. Am I able to just keep those files without a problem or is it best to delete them?

Comment: It won’t cause any problems if you keep them.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still need this but.. I found that adding 'sudo' in front of the command works, I ran into the same issue and I was able to manually remove them using the admin account. Also, like @zja mentioned, you want to make sure there is a space between '-rm -rf' and the file path.

Example:
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew/share/

Oh, and you can go directly navigate to the homebrew file to see if the files were removed via the terminal.

sudo open /opt/homebrew/ for example opens the homebrew folder and you can visually see if the files are still there.